# Abstract function to sum elements of an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have like 40 different arrays and I want to find the average value of each of them.
In order to do it with each one, I have this code:

```
var SumArray1 = 0;
var avgArray1 = 0;

$.each(array1,function() {
    SumArray1 += this;
    avgArray1 = (SumArray1)/(array1.length);
    });
```

But as I have those 40 arrays, I was trying to look for a way to make that function abstract, but I don't know how to introduce parameters for a function using $.each and I don't think having forty functions would be the right thing to do... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
Array.prototype.average = function() {
    var s = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
        s += this[i];
    }
    return s/this.length;
}
```

Then at any point you can do something like

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var calculatedAverage = myArray.average();  // This will equal 2.5
```

Comment: With JavaScript 1.6 or later, instead of an explicit `for` loop, you could use `this.forEach(function(val) { s += val; });`. You should also check that `Array.prototype.average` doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation calculates the average each time, but it only gets a correct value the last time. This is not necesary.

Also, there's no need to use `$.each`, which forces you to use an additional closure (my previous statement about waiting was wrong, since `$.each` is synchronous).

The following is simpler:

```
function avgArray(array) {
   var i,l,s = 0;
   for (i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++) s+= array[i];

   return s/l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have a built in reduce function, if you like short one-liners you can also do this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

function sum(x,y){
    return x + y;
}

var total = arr.reduce(sum); // total -> 10

// This also works
var total = arr.reduce( function(x,y) { return (x + y); } );

var avg = ( total / arr.length );
```

Reduce is a higher-order function that 'reduces' an sequence into a single value.

Here is the execution flow of reduce.

```
var temp = sum( arr[0], arr[1] );
temp = sum( temp, arr[2] );
temp = sum( temp, arr[3] );
return temp;
```

Stealing Andrew Shepherd answer for adding new functions to the Array data structure.

```
Array.prototype.sum = function() { return this.reduce( function(x,y) { return (x+y); } )};
Array.prototype.avg = function() { return (this.sum() / this.length) };
```